# collect location via form

Tags: software-recommendations, data-collection

I'm trying to find if there is some solutions for collect data from users via some easy form (not google forms, something more powerful)?

I heard about arcgis collector, but you have to log in (so not everyone can submit a form) and it's mostly for organisation rather than for a large public..

Is it possible to collect this data not by manual writing input from users, but by simple click on a map joined to the form?

Comment: It sounds like you are after a software recommendation for which there is a [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange available.

Comment: Could be, but I think it's should be something already existing, like https://www.fixmystreet.com/..

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution myself: ESRI already developed a perfect web-application called [GEOFORM](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=931653256fd24301a84fc77955914a82). It adds points which users select to the shapefile, so you can even create your own database without too much work

There is another solution, also from ESRI: [Survey123](https://survey123.arcgis.com/). For some needs it's even better